# conversion error while grouping the data and returning as JSON

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

With the help of another developer from stackoverflow, I managed to use his query to create a code which returns me data back based upon grouping by groupid and return as json

Try using the following concept:

Insert data:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (some_data VARCHAR(20), some_other_data VARCHAR(20), groupId VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO some_table (some_data, some_other_data, groupId) values ('a', '1', 'id1');
INSERT INTO some_table (some_data, some_other_data, groupId) values ('b', '2', 'id1');
INSERT INTO some_table (some_data, some_other_data, groupId) values ('c', '3', 'id2');
```

Execute the query:

```
SELECT '{"' + t.groupId + '": [{' + STUFF(
          (
            SELECT '{ "some_data":"' + td.some_data + '"', ', "some_other_data":' + td.some_other_data + '},'
            FROM some_table td
            WHERE t.groupId = td.groupId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
          ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') + ']}'
FROM some_table t
GROUP BY t.groupId
```

Results:

```
{"id1": [{ "some_data":"a", "some_other_data":1},{ "some_data":"b","some_other_data":2},]}

{"id2": [{ "some_data":"c","some_other_data":3},]}
```

Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/66b19/35

But i run this i see an error

```
Error   SQL Server Database Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '{"' to data type int.   4   0
```

Comment: Can't get your sample to fail on several versions of sql-server (2008,2012,2016). The main reason you'd see that error is b/c int has a higher precedence that varchar, and when + is applied between an int and a varchar both must convert to int.

Answer (score 0):

Jason array format can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp)

Looking at the example in the link you can see that you have an extra brace and an extra coma.

Solution:
Move `,` (coma) from `+ '},'` to `',{ "some_data":"`

Remove extra curly brace: `'": [{' + STUFF(` -> `'": [' + STUFF(`

**Update:**
Non-varchar columns will need to be converted to `(N)VARCHAR`: `CONVERT( NVARCHAR, [field] )`

Final Query:

```
SELECT '{"' + t.groupId + '": [' + STUFF(
          (
            SELECT ',{ "some_data":"' + td.some_data + '"', ', "some_other_data":' + CONVERT( NVARCHAR, td.some_other_data ) + '}'
            FROM some_table td
            WHERE t.groupId = td.groupId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
          ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') + ']}'
FROM some_table t
GROUP BY t.groupId
```

P.S. looks like https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427001/6305294 simply has made a typo with the brace

Comment: I am still getting that conversion error, Just to tell you the fields are all numeric, no varchar

Comment: Wrap your numeric fields in `CONVERT( NVARCHAR, [field] )` function to convert them to varchar. You example table has all fields as varchar BTW.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on MSSQL 2016:

```
SELECT t.groupId,
    (
    SELECT td.some_data, td.some_other_data
    FROM some_table td
    WHERE t.groupId = td.groupId
    FOR JSON PATH
    ) As json_data
FROM some_table t
GROUP BY t.groupId
```

You can find the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server